# In Android, how do I insert text into the textbox the user is currently using?

Tags: android

I'm building what is essentially a character map. The user would invoke it as a popup dialog, and after touching a desired character, it would be inserted into the current editor, **which is in another application**. What I want is essentially a "send keys" type of behavior.

Is there a way to do this without becoming an Input Method? If I have to become an Input Method, can it be used alongside normal keyboards, or does it have to replace them?

Also, if the API doesn't let you do that, I'm okay requiring root for this, though I'd prefer not to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom modified "popup" which listens to  `onTouch() or onClick()` events for the editor input box.

Its up to you how to design this qwerty layout. It should be simple and you dont have to root your phone.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. The input box isn't part of my application. You would invoke this activity, from say, Messaging, and it would insert a character for you.

Comment: Ok you *should* have mentioned it in the question. I'll get back to you on this. Can you also tell me what character set are you using?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on that. The character set could be UTF-8 or even Latin1 for test purposes.

Comment: This apparently isn't doable in Android.